# Select count sql statement with php

Tags: php, mysql

I am going to develop a online ticket booking system. I have two database table coach_shedule and seat. coache_shedule contains the coach details information with coach_id as primary key and table seat contains seat that is booked from online.

```
 table "coach_shedule"

coach_id    cdate     ctime     coach_no     route

 table "seat"

 seat_id    name     seat_no    coach_id
```

I have three select field on browser that returns route, cdate and ctime
using this three field I have get coach_id from coach_shedule table using select query
and I save the seat in table seat that is booked from browser.
Every coach has 40 seat. I want to show on browser using php how many seat is booked of each coach coach.

Here is my problem,
In my code I wanted to show the number of seat of each coach that is booked and I have written code in the last column of html table named "seat booked". but it does not show the proper result. I think I explained my problem properly. Please help me. If you want to know specific point. Please ask me.

```
<form action="coach_time.php" method="post"><table width="100%" style="font-    size:small">
<tr>
<td width="30"></td>
<td>Route</td><td>
<select name="route" size="1" class="selhead" id="cdate" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<option value="Dhaka-Barisal"<?php if($route=="Dhaka-Barisal") {echo "selected";} ?> onclick="this.parentNode.form.submit()">Dhaka-Barisal</option>
      <option value="Barisal-Dhaka"<?php if($route=="Barisal-Dhaka") {echo "selected";} ?> onclick="this.parentNode.form.submit()">Barisal-Dhaka</option>
      </select>
</td>
</tr></form>




<table width="100%" style="font-size:small">
<tr>
<th>Serial</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Coach Type</th>
<th>Day Night</th>
<th>Fare</th>
<th>Seat booked</th>
</tr>

<?php
 $sql=mysql_query("select * from coach_shedule where route='$route' and cdate='$cdate'");

  $a=1;
  while($data=mysql_fetch_row($sql))
  {
  ?>
 <tr>
   <td align="center"><?php echo $a; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data[1]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data[2]; ?></td>

<td><?php echo $data[4]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data[5]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data[6]; ?></td>
<td><?php 
$coachid=$data[0];
$sql1=mysql_query("select seat_no from seat where coach_id='$coachid'");
$data1=mysql_num_rows($sql);
echo  $data1;

?></td>
</tr>


  <?php
  $a++;
  }
  ?>

    </table>
```

Comment: We don't need to see your HTML

Comment: Can you explain what you are looking for or what isn't working?

Comment: I can't see where `$route` and `$cdate` are defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got an error here:

```
'$sql1=mysql_query("select seat_no from seat where coach_id='$coachid'");
 $data1=mysql_num_rows(**$sql**);'
```

should be

```
 $data1=mysql_num_rows(**$sql1**);'
```

You are using the wrong SQL there.

Edit: more explanation